# flask to write data into file

Tags: python, python-2.7, flask

I have problem to write data into file from my flask developments server (win7),

```
 @app.route('/')
 def main():

    fo = open("test.txt","wb")
    fo.write("This is Test Data")

 return render_template('index.html')
```

Why this don't works in flask ?

Comment: Add a `fo.flush()` line after write.

Comment: I would add fo.close() at the end just in case

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You should either `flush` the output to the file or `close` the file because the data may still be present in the I/O buffer.

Even better use the `with` statement as it'll automatically close the file for you.

```
with open("test.txt", "w") as fo:
   fo.write("This is Test Data")
```

Comment: While this is good advice, I didn't get it to work. The `"wb"` flag indicates that binary data is expected rather than strings, but in `fo.write` a string is sent, resulting in the following error:
`TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'`. I recommend changing `"wb"` to `"w"` in order to write strings to file.

Comment: @Helena This answer is from Python 2 days, where str/bytes were same and unicode was a separate type. Updated to replace `wb` with `w`.

Answer (score 1):

@Ashwini's answer is likely correct, but I wanted to point out that if you are writing to a file to have a logfile, then you should use Flask's support for logging instead. This is based on Python's `logging` module, which is very flexible. Documentation [here](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/errorhandling/#logging-to-a-file).

Answer (score 1):

```
@app.route('/')
def main():
    fo= open("test.txt", "w")
    filebuffer = ["brave new world"]
    fo.writelines(filebuffer)
    fo.close()
    return render_template('index.html')
```

Comment: Why this should answer OP question ?